# Maplibre and Rails 7 importmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps, maplibre-gl

in `config/importmap.rb`:

```
pin "maplibre-gl", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:maplibre-gl@3.3.1/dist/maplibre-gl.js"
```

However, trying to use this library: `import * as maplibregl from "maplibre-gl"` (or a range of variants of this), results in the error: `Could not resolve "maplibre-gl"`

*Edit based on Alex's feedback: It seems I can reference the import map imported library from a page or partial. However, I can't reference it from a Stimulus controller. I've adjusted the question to reflect this.*

Does anybody know how to use import maps to reference (and use) MapLibre from a *Stimulus controller*? And, why would it be different from there?

Restarting the server (`bin/dev`) has no effect.

My guess is that MapLibre is not exporting its modules etc correctly. But validating that, or working around this problem, is probably beyond me.

I would expect that maplibre could be included as a script in the head section of the html document. But, that doesn't feel like the most sensible way to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems to work just fine. where exactly are you importing it? do the rest of your pins work? `Could not resolve "maplibre-gl"` - doesn't look like an importmap error, which would be `Failed to resolve module specifier "maplibre-gl"`

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful. Using import maps as described above, I can reference `maplibre-gl` from a partial or page, so: `<script type="module">  import * as maplibregl from "maplibre-gl"`. Works fine (although, I have to reference things with a `.default`: `maplibregl.default.Map`, but let's not worry about details yet). However, I can't reference maplibre-gl from a stimulus controller. Which is, a useful clue. Thanks.

Comment: it would be exactly the same in stimulus controller, you have to import it and then reference it in that controller.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the reason I was struggling is that the import prefixes the imported module with `default`.

So, import as follows:

```
import * as maplibregl from "maplibre-gl"
```

Reference as:

```
new maplibregl.default.Map
```

Note the use of `default`.